# Como usar o site parse.com?

Tags: android, banco-de-dados, parse.com

Com o [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) é necessário passar a minha base de dados para o site deles?

Tenho uma base de dados no servidor da empresa e não pretendo colocar no site deles. Eles oferecem a opção de aceder a minha base dados sem ser pelo site deles?

Por exemplo sempre que for adicionada 1 coluna na minha base de dados aparecer uma notificação na minha *app*?

Já agora o parse é totalmente gratuito ou tem por exemplo um x número de notificações que podem ser enviadas e após esse número passar a ser preciso ser membro premium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O parse é um sdk cloud para desenvolvimento rápido de aplicativos. Com ele é possível armazenar dados, enviar notificações, e-mails, controlar instalações e mais um monte de coisas que o app precisa.

Não é necessário armazenar os dados da sua empresa lá, você pode simplesmente enviar notificações [Push](https://parse.com/products/push) para seus clientes quando você achar conveniente direto do seu sistema.

Para que o [push](https://parse.com/products/push) funcione é necessário incluir o SDK do parse no seu projeto mobile e registrar a instalation. O [site](https://parse.com/products/push) tem um [passo a passo](https://parse.com/tutorials/android-push-notifications), se você seguir vai conseguir fazer sem problema algum. Eu mesmo já fiz para android e iOs, é realmente fácil.

Quanto aos limites o parse tem alguns planos [aqui](https://parse.com/plans). Pessoalmente eu sempre usei, e uso até hoje, e nunca paguei nada, entretanto ele conta a quantidade de acessos a API e pode te cobrar caso você envie muitas solicitações mensais, então isso vai do seu bom senso.

Uma coisa que você não perguntou, mas eu vou te dizer, é que o parse tem um grande problema com latência, logo ele não é muito bom para guardar dados que precisam ser consultados e carregados o tempo todo. Use com moderação.

Comment: Off topic: Uma vez eu comecei a escrever um curso de Parse mas não acabei. Quem sabe um dia eu continuo. Aqui está ele: http://edgarberlinck.blogspot.com.br/p/curso-desenvolvimento-de-aplicativos.html

Comment: Sabe me dizer se a utilização do serviço, dentro dos limites *free*, pode ser utilizado em aplicações pagas?

Comment: Não sei cara. Acho que seria mais interessante dar uma lida no FAQ e nos termos de serviço deles.